# Qt getting reference of custom data type of QStandardItemModel to change it

Tags: qt, reference, qtableview

It's getting a little weird I can't see a method to actually change the "data" of a QStandardItemModel. For example:

```
struct TestStruct {
    std::vector<int> testVector;
    void addNumber(int i){  
        //this method will modify the member vector
    }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(TestStruct)

QStandardItemModel* model = QStandardItemModel(1,1);
QModelIndex index = model->index(0,0);
TestStruct test;
test.addNumber(1);
model->setData(index, qVariantFromValue(test));
```

With that, I will effectively have added a std::vector with the number 1 to the index {0,0} of the model. But how would I add another number to that TestStruct's vector from places that don't have access to the TestStruct instance anymore?

The "data" function returns a QVariant that can be casted as a TestStruct but it's a copy and I need a reference... get it?

Comment: Also, what is the rationale behind making the struct as an item in the QStandardItemModel? Anyhow you will not be able to use it in any of the Views directly.. Why are you doing it??

Comment: I use Delegates to properly show the items as I want to. For example, lets say you had a list of cars with their own available colors, and you would like to render that in a QTableView, but of course since one car can have many available colors you show them as a combobox? How would you do that? I'm really very new to QT.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will return the value only and not it's reference.

A workaround for this is, you can get the `struct` by Typecasting the `QVariant`. Then modify your `testVector`.

After modifications, call **again**

```
model->setData(index, qVariantFromValue(newTest));
```

where **`newTest` is your `struct` with the modified Vector**.

Hope it helps.